# Cannot deploy branch to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm trying to manually deploy branch *main* from [my repository](https://github.com/jurok3x/my-site/) to Heroku using the simple git deployment method on the Heroku website. However, I get the following log:

> ```
> -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
> -----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
> -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-> registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
>        Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git.
>        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
>  !     Push failed
> ```

Can not understand why it ignores `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pom.xml` file should be in the root of your project. In this way is found by Heroku that activates (by default) the Java support for Maven.

Move the file or (better/easier) avoid using the `demo-site` folder (store POM, src, etc.. in the root).